# How can get a quassel-client and quassel-core irc setup and running?

Tags: installation, irc

I want to use quassel to access my irc channels from multiple laptops, and want to know how to get it set up. I have a server I will install the core on and several laptops that will run the client. How can I get the perfect quassel irc setup?

Comment: Appologies, I don't have the reputation to comment on the previous answer, but the link is dead. Here is a link to the cashed version: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:v4T5AaLDhUIJ:www.ubuntu-tennessee.org/2009/tutorials/using-quassel-in-a-client-core-setup/+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk

Answer (score 1):

On system with quassle-core installed, I ran the setup via GUI (found this out when started CLI setup)

1. Start client (not stand-alone) and configure core setup
2. Create admin account
3. Configure IRC servers

On other client, I did the following:

1. Install Quassel client
2. Configure to connect to Quassel core

Here are older directions that do not use the GUI: http://www.ubuntu-tennessee.org/2009/tutorials/using-quassel-in-a-client-core-setup/